ERROR TypeError: Error.stack getter called with an invalid receiver, js engine: hermes
I am very new to React-Native and this is my first question in stack overflow
In EXPO , while changing file _layout.tsx to _layout.jsx of the RootLayout
this eoor is showing in my terminal:
Failed to print error:  Error.stack getter called with an invalid receiver
ERROR  TypeError: Error.stack getter called with an invalid receiver, js engine: hermes
on clicking project 
this error is showing in the virtual phone
and this is showing in my termianal
how to resolve this
thanks in advance
I have restarted my system and reload in termainal also but still my project is not working

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
